# Calculate values from a MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need a code that can calculate values from my MySQL DB together. Like:

```
X got the values: 21, 23, 41, 98
Y got the values: 12, 92, 52, 78
```

Now I want to get a sum of X and a sum of Y to echo them out. The output should be, X = 183 and not X = 4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use the MySQL `SUM()` function to do this?

Comment: Try to follow this guidance before you ask: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I see you've got an answer below, but what would be really useful here is to see what code you used to get the answer 4. I can guess, but I shouldn't have to - which I suspect is why you have been downvoted. Please always add enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

you can use SUM()

select SUM(X) + SUM(Y) as totalofXandY from table1;

now

echo $row['totalofXandY'];

this will give sum of X and Y

Comment: Just so you know, you can use backticks (`) to highlight inline code, and indents of four spaces to highlight code blocks. See Sumit's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used [The SUM() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) in SQL before?

```
select SUM(X) from table1;
select SUM(Y) from table1;
```

Just a hint! ;)

This is of course if your X and Y values are specified each per row.
i.e.

```
table1
x    y
---  ---
21   12
23   92
41   52
98   78
```

and not as

```
table1
x            y
------------ ------------
21,23,41,98  12,92,52,78
```

this make a big difference!

And I think you are confused between SUM and COUNT.

> SUM(X) will give you 183 (the total sum of all X contents)
>
> COUNT(X) will give you 4 (it is the occurrences of X).

Comment: Yes, my fail, it is like you did in upper one, had not know how to display it like you did, sry

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SUM()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm) function

```
SELECT SUM(x) as total FROM table_name;
```

then echo it.

```
echo $row['total'];
```